# HTML picture loop

Tags: html, image

I want to make a picture appear 4-5 or even more times, in a row without writing it 4 or 5 times:

```
<img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:16px;height:16px">
<img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:16px;height:16px">
<img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:16px;height:16px">
<img src="images/favicon.ico" style="width:16px;height:16px">
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I have a picture that I want to make it appear on screen multiple times, like a movie review, when you see a logo 4-5 times as a movie rate

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var count = 5;
var index = 1;

while (index <= count) {
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += '<img src="http://wfarm1.dataknet.com/static/resources/icons/set95/5076c9d9.png" style="width:16px;height:16px">';

    console.log(index);
    index++;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vgz5pukg/

Comment: yeah thanks! I will edit it and I will make it work like I want! Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to select this as the answer to your question....

Answer (score 1):

You could try using something like a div then style it, but that would still be 4 divs, just shorter. To have dynamic markup, you'd need to use PHP. Also possible to use JavaScript to do that, but it wouldn't be an elegant solution.

Edit: for PHP, this would do the trick:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    echo "<img src='images/favicon.ico' style='width:16px;height:16px'>";
}
```